# Is there any difference between function($var) and function() use ($var)?

Tags: php, closures

Is there any differences between those?

```
$something = function($var) { 

});

$something = function() use ($var) {

});
```

Comment: Both function has an extra `)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The former is a function with a single parameter named `$var`. If there's another `$var` defined elsewhere in the script, it doesn't matter; the function won't contain a reference to it inside its scope (within its definition).

For example.

```
$bar = 3;
function foo($bar) {
   if (isset($bar)) {
      echo "bar: $bar";
   } else {
      echo "no bar";
   } 
}
foo(10); // prints "bar: 10", because the function is called with the argument "10"
foo(); // prints "no bar" -- $bar is not defined inside the function scope
```

In the case of the latter, the `use $var` closure means that a definition of $var in the containing scope will be accessible, like a global variable, inside the function.

For example,

```
$bar = 3;
function foo($blee) use $bar {
   if (isset($bar)) {
      echo "bar: $bar";
   } else {
      echo "no bar";
   }
   if (isset($input)) {
      echo "input: $input";
   } else {
      echo "no input";
   }
}
foo(1); // prints "bar: 3, input: 1"
foo(); // prints "bar: 3, no input"
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a function taking a single parameter, the other one is a function taking no parameters and closing over the value of the variable `$var` from the parent scope.